# Batik URL exception in Windows

Tags: java, windows, svg, batik

I'm working on this program that does some manual parsing and changing svg files where I'm only using Batik to create previews of the SVG files in question.

It's supposed to read all SVG files within a directory and to show the images I'm using Batik along with this transcoder class I found online as a suggestion for another program some time ago:

```
public class BufferedImageTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {
        private BufferedImage image = null;     
        @Override
        public BufferedImage createImage(int weight, int height)
        {
            return new BufferedImage(weight, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }   
        @Override
        public void writeImage(BufferedImage image, TranscoderOutput output) throws TranscoderException
        {
            this.image = image;
        }
        public BufferedImage getBufferedImage()
        {
            return image;
        }

        public static BufferedImage loadImage(File svgFile, float width, float height) {
            BufferedImageTranscoder imageTranscoder = new BufferedImageTranscoder();
            imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, width);
            imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, height);
            try {
                String path = svgFile.getCanonicalPath();
                System.out.println(path);
                TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(path);
                if(input != null)
                    imageTranscoder.transcode(input, null);
            } catch (TranscoderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return imageTranscoder.getBufferedImage();
        }
}
```

On macOS this program seems to work perfectly fine without issues, but when I load the project into Eclipse in Windows I get this exception:

> Enclosed Exception: Unable to make sense of URL for connection    at
>   org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)

Any idea what causes this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Probably you have some problem with the path/names of files that you are trying to load.

Comment: I found that using the InputStream constructor for the TranscoderInput class makes the exception disappear, so at least I found a workaround.

Comment: url in svg file having problem.